# OpenGL ES, rotate rectangle in vertex array

Tags: opengl-es, matrix, rotation, vertex

I'm trying to rotate a rectangle in place I mean rotate its coordinates in the vertex array, before the array is passed to GL for rendering.

I have a rectangle defined like this:

```
vect0 = -1.0, 0.0, 0
vect1 = -1.0, 1.0, 0 
vect2 = 1.0, 1.0, 0
vect3 = 1.0, 0, 0

GLfloat verts[] = {vect0,vect1,vect2,vect3};
```

Is there any way to rotate these coordinates in such a way that when the rectangle is rendered, it will appear rotated at an arbitrary angle on the x,y or z axis?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a rotation matrix. Depending on which version of OpenGL ES you are writing for, this could be as simple as `glRotatef` (1.0/1.1) or you would need to use a math library to create the matrix and send it over to your shader. (2.0)

If you absolutely have to create the rotation before sending the vertices off, use a math library and multiply each vertex by the rotation matrix. I wouldn't recommend it though unless you're absolutely 100% sure that the vertices will never rotate after initial rotation.